# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, jakarta-mail

All i'm trying to do here is get the Mail sender to work from my Java code.

I looked at a similar issue and also removed the spring version numbers as suggested here [cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015240/cvc-complex-type-2-4-c-the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can) but I still see the same error.

```
Mar 21, 2017 9:04:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationcontext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 86; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'bean'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:604)
```

My applicationContext is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
     <property name="host" value="postman.mx.domain.com"/>
     <property name="username" value="email@domain.com"/>
     <property name="javaMailProperties" >
         <props>
             <prop key="mail.smtp.auth" >false</prop>
         </props>
     </property>
 </bean>
```

I also have an entry in my pom.xml for javax mail as follows:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the proper namespace to the `bean` element by changing,

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
```

to

```
<bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
```

and your error will go away.

Comment: This removed the error on tomcat startup like a charm but also made all my other working web services throw a HTTP 500 :/

Comment: One problem at a time.  Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer and ask a new question for your new problems.  Thanks.

Comment: Accepted the answer. Added the new question here. Please take a look if you get a chance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942032/beancreationexception-after-fixing-namespace-issues

Comment: Basically seeing  error which were working before org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is